# Fill datagrid specific defined columns from mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with 7 defined columns I want to fill 4 of theme from MySQL database so I tried this:

**XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Stock.Resource.Transaction.Vente"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
         xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Stock.Resource.Transaction"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="530" d:DesignWidth="1218">
<Grid>
    <DatePicker x:Name="Date" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="Vendeur" Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Selectionner un Vendeur" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,151,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
    <Button x:Name="Effect" Content="Effectué" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,211,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Effect_Click"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="Produit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="240,64,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxHeight="456" MaxWidth="968">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Produit" Binding="{Binding Produit}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Stock" Binding="{Binding Stock}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Prix" Binding="{Binding Prix}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantié"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Prix Unitaire" Binding="{Binding Prix Unitaire}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unitée"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Totale"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**C#**

```
public void FillGrid(DataGrid data, string query)
{
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConStr().ToString());
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("concour");
            da.Fill(dt);
            data.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            da.Update(dt);
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var v = new ModernDialog
            {
                Title = "Error",
                Content = ex.Message
            };
            v.Buttons = new Button[] { v.OkButton };
            var r = v.ShowDialog();
        }
}
```

and it works fine just that I get double column that I want to fill.

This is the query that I used:

```
SELECT 
    designation As 'Produit', stock As 'Stock', 
    prix As 'Prix', prixu As 'Prix Unitaire' 
FROM 
    produit 
WHERE 
    DELETED = 'N';
```

Comment: What do you mean with "I get double column"?

Comment: in the datagrid i got 2 clulns named produit and 2 named Stock and 2 named Prix and 2 named Prix Unitaire

Comment: Set the [AutoGenerateColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx) to false.

Comment: And I don't know if "Prix Unitaire" will work as binding. Beter change the name of the field to "Prix_Unitaire".

Comment: it work even with "Prix Unitaire" thnx.  can you help me with that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39184976/datagrid-operation-between-columns/39185203#39185203 ??

Comment: If it work, can you answer your question and accept the answer? Other people may have benefit of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All it's need is to Set the `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false`.