# datagrid operation between columns

Tags: c#, mysql, datagrid

this the datagrid i got

```
+==========+==========+==========+==========+
| Product  |  Price   | quantity |   Total  |
+==========+==========+==========+==========+
```

so i got Product and Price from MySQL database (Table1). and user enter number in the quantity cell and the program calculat the Total (Total=Price*quantity) the save it in Table2 (in MySQL).

this is an example

```
+==========+==========+==========+==========+
| Product  |  Price   | quantity |   Total  |
+==========+==========+==========+==========+
|  AAAAA   |    30    |    2     |    60    |
+==========+==========+==========+==========+
```

**UPDATE**

I add CellEditEndding handler like this

```
private void Produit_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ((DataView)Produit.ItemsSource).ToTable();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            row["total"] = (Convert.ToDouble(row["price"]) * Convert.ToDouble(row["quantity"]));
        }
        Produit.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
```

when i edit a quantity cell every thing is return to 0.

**NOTE**: when I'm filling the DataGrid i Fill quantity an total with zoros

Comment: So what is your question? (And what you have tried in order to solve it?)

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate a total after your user enters a number into the quantity column?

Comment: You can show the result to the user by using an Expression Column.  Not sure why it is a different table since they look the same

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: how can i make the operation Total=Price*quantity when the user enter a value in quantity

Comment: You can add en event handler on the [CellEditEnding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34423422/wpf-datagrid-cell-value-changed-event) event

Comment: @DDDSoft i UPDATE the question

Comment: As discribed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcelleditendingeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx), you can easely get the row with e.row

Comment: @DDDSoft can't find an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand your question, you want to ask that the user just enter the product code and quantity then the price and total-price automatically add to the `data grid view`. For that purpose you need to add `Label field` with the help of `TemplateField` in your `data grid column` Like this

```
      <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblprice" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTotalPrice" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
```

Then access the label to server side

```
Label lblprice= (Label)row.FindControl("lblprice");
Label lblTotalPrice= (Label)row.FindControl("lblTotalPrice");
```

Now just assign the values to these labels.